# If statement not catching nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following function:

```
def price
  if super == nil
    return 'super'
  end
  super
end
```

`nil` is being returned. How is this possible? Should the if statement catch super if it equals nil and then return 'super'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `super` can return different values each time, this is possible (if unlikely). Perhaps try the following? It only calls `super` once, so it doesn't have that pitfall.

```
def price
  super || 'super'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a very strange way of saying something that should be expressed more simply as:

```
def price
  super || 'super'
end
```

It might be the case that the second call to the same method returns `nil` for some reason. You're not capturing the initial result so it's hard to say why this isn't working.